# How to get a list of opened files for a script under Linux?

Tags: linux

Let's say, I would like to figure out what **pip install** does, like what files are downloaded, where are they extracted, where is the temporary files, ...

Are there any suggested way to track the opened files by script under Linux?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [Inotify](http://www.infoq.com/articles/inotify-linux-file-system-event-monitoring). It tracks down changes to files and directories under a given path. And there are lot of options to make it work like you want. And also, this is not process dependent, so you get any changes made by any process or script.

You can also have a look at [fschange](http://stefan.buettcher.org/cs/fschange/index.html), which uses inotify as backend.

And if you want a GUI tool, check out [DaemonFS](http://www.giowisys.com/en/products/daemonfs/).

Comment: Using inotify, is there any way to determine which files were modified by which programs?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "lsof" command to get a list of open files, for a process with a particular pid.   Here's a useful introduction: http://www.akadia.com/services/lsof_intro.html

To get the process id of the command, you could do something like ps ax | grep pip. Then just pass that to lsof like so: lsof -p theprocessid

Comment: Then, my next question is how to get that process id asap cause the script is running so fast. Furthermore, because it's a script, some file accessing is done by other programs/scripts instead!

Comment: In that case, a better approach may be to use strace, combined with the -f option to "follow" child processes.  You're going to get a *lot* more output though :)  You can just run it like strace -f pip install.  Or what Bibhas said :)